# Return error from models

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following model:

```
   internal static List<Contracts.DataContracts.Report> GetReportsForSearch(string searchVal, string searchParam)
    {
        var param1 = new SqlParameter("@SearchVal", searchVal);
        var ctx = new StradaDataReviewContext2();
        var reports = new List<Contracts.DataContracts.Report>();

        try 
        {
    //Validate param1 here and return false if the requirment are not met
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    //Throw
    }
}
```

param1 here Is a value entered by a user and I want to validate It here, and If the requirements are not met, I want to return an error.

But how can I return an error here from the model? The method Is of the type List, and I can't not just write `return false` in this method.

Any suggestion how to do It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good that you didn't thought about throwing an exception, when requirements are not met. We shouldn't use exceptions for controlling program flow.

I have two options in my mind :

**1. Use objects**

Modify your `GetReportsForSearch` method to following signature:

```
internal static List<Contracts.DataContracts.Report> GetReportsForSearch(string searchVal,
                                                      string searchParam, ReportRequestor requestor)
{
    var param1 = new SqlParameter("@SearchVal", searchVal);
    var ctx = new StradaDataReviewContext2();
    var reports = new List<Contracts.DataContracts.Report>();

    try 
    {
        //Validate param1 here and call RequirementsAreNotMet method if the requirements are not met
        requestor.RequirementsAreNotMet();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    //Throw
    }
}
```

And then you can implement code responsible for handling this situation in `ReportRequestor` class

```
public class ReportRequestor
{
    public void RequiremenrsAreNotMet()
    {
        //code which handle situation when requiremenets are not met
    }
}
```

**2. Use return type as indicator of status**

In this way, when requirements are not met you should create `ReportGenerationStatus` object with `HasResult` flag set to false.
In other case just set `HasResult` to true and also set results accordingly. This somewhat mimics [`Option`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) type known from functional languages

```
internal static ReportGenerationStatus GetReportsForSearch(string searchVal, string searchParam)
{
    //code for your method
}

public class ReportGenerationStatus
{
    public List<Contracts.DataContracts.Report> Result { get; set; }
    public bool HasResult { get; set; }
}
```